# Changes not saved in SQL Server Management Studio after deattach

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a DB in SQL Server 2008. I develop the database with adding some new tables. Finally I detach and again attach it. But the applied changes (redesign, add and drop tables) do not exist any more...

What happen? Why can I not save changes in database?

Comment: How did you modify your tables? Did you create a script and actually execute it?

Comment: @SeanLange no I used managment studio's interface. Simply, **Right click on Table** folder --> then **New Table**

Comment: Ugh. You really should use scripts to create objects. It may be a little bit slower initially but in the long run it will be much faster. That aside, did you save those tables before you detached? Just pulling up the UI to create a table does not create the table. You have to save it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I saved it and it asked me to save it as **Table_1** and I renamed it to ***another name** .......

Comment: I've seen this question before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052519/changes-in-table-design-does-not-save) with no answers posted.

Comment: Also found a similar question [on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/df68c3f9-626d-44ba-b105-7e506e71e6e5/lost-table-data-after-detaching-and-reataching-a-database-mssql-2008?forum=sqldatabaseengine) ... try reviewing the answers posted there.

Comment: Did you move, copy, rename, or otherwise touch the .mdf OR .ldf file?

Comment: @AHiggins yes i move *.mdf to another folder. why?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/64582/) might help you to understand the issue:

When changes are made to the database, the transaction log containing those changes is captured in the .LDF file.  After some time, the changes are transferred over into the .MDF file, which is what you moved and reattached.

If you detached the database before that process was done, the information about your table changes hadn't yet gone over to the .mdf file.  When you attached the database, then, it only 'knew' about the .mdf file, not the .ldf file, and was missing your changes.

Try this:  copy the .ldf file along with the .mdf file into your new directory, and attach the database from there.  It should have all changes.

Comment: Thanks,but Do u think backup or copy database and use BACKUP and RESTORE instead of detaching.

Comment: [That discussion](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/attach-detach-v-s-backup-restore) is probably [a separate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) ... I'd like to verify if the suggested change fixes the issue before moving on to that question, which will depend on a lot of other factors.